# Changing values of a cell based upon multiple values of a drop down

Tags: cell, google-docs

Hopefully someone can help me.
I have created a drop down list in a cell with multiple values i.e. A,B,C,D.
When each value from the list is selected I would like a corresponding value in another cell to be set i.e.

Cell A4 values A,B,C,D

Cell A5 corresponding values 12,13,14,15

I have seen code to swap a single value but not multiple values.
Any help greatly appreciated

Thanks

Matt

Comment: Excel? `table`? html?

Comment: Hello, I'm trying to do this in a Google spreadsheet.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to setup a Vlookup table so when A, B, C, or D changes it looks through a table.

Make a table with the values how you like.

a  12
b  13
c  14
d  15

Name this table.

Then in cell A5 fill out the vlookup.  It would look something like this

=Vlookup(A4,The name of your table,2,0)

Comment: Thanks for gettung back I will give that a try